# Cannot saving form in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So i'm using the **auth.models.user** to create user model and by default it's passing  ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'). and the **forms.py**:

```
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = user

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Username'
        self.fields['email'].label = "Email Address"
```

i try to allowing user to edit their personal information from all avaliable fields in  UserSignUpForm, **except** the password fields. so i created this **views.py** (function based view):

```
def edit_account(request):
    user = request.user
    form = UserSignUpForm(instance=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST, instance=user,)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form = UserSignUpForm(instance=user)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated.')
        return redirect('/dashboard/profile/')
    context = {'editform':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/updateaccounts.html', context)
```

tried submit the specific field form like{{editform.first_name}} after passsing it in the html page (because i dont want to user be able edit their password)  but it still not update/saving the new user data. is there any method so it can be save? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the html file, have you tried printing the form errors to see what's happening? try this:

```
<form method = "POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
</form>
```

Also, you have a "  form = UserSignUpForm(instance=user)" outside of the if request.POST...

You also have a "  form = UserSignUpForm(instance=user)" after form is valid.